# InternalResourceViewResolver Not Resolving

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

As much as I have done with Spring, I have never done anything with Spring MVC and wanted to experiment to see how it compares with things I know better like Grails and Rails. I have a trivial application with a single JSP and a single controller endpoint, but I have been unable to get Spring MVC to resolve my path to the JSP.

Here is *web.xml* in *WEB-INF*:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>     
 <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

Here is *dispatcher-servlet.xml* in WEB-INF:

```
<beans...>    
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springapp"/>
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:my.properties"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="/webjars/"/>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

And my one controller in the `com.springapp` package:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

Meanwhile, there is a file called *hello.jsp* in *WEB-INF/jsp*.

When I navigate to "/" in my application, I get a 404 when I figured I would get *hello.jsp*.

I also have an integration test that confirms the same problem by failing with a 404:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration("file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml")
public class AppIT {
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaAutowiringInspection")
    @Autowired
    protected WebApplicationContext wac;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testMVC() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(view().name("hello"));
    }
}
```

I am sure I am missing something obvious, so I would love the Spring MVC experts to tell me what that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` to your spring configuration, this tells Spring MVC to pickup annotations such as `@RequestMapping`.

See the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-annotation-driven) for further information regarding `annotation-driven`.

Comment: Interestingly, that worked so my manual requests pass, but my test still fails. Still an upvote of course. Any thoughts? Is my form of testing incorrect?

Comment: @Vidya Any exceptions when the test runs? Maybe try providing the entire url instead of `/`

Comment: No exception; only `java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<404>`. And no change with the full URL. Weird. But I guess that's a question for another day. Thanks for pointing out that `context:component-scan` isn't enough.

Comment: Hi Kevin, I am having similar issue, but I have included the said tag in my spring configuration. Any idea why it could fail then? I am new to spring MVC so kind of learning from online tutorials. I encountered this issue while doing one assignment.